# Using AspCompat in a SharePoint web part page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm in the process of creating a SharePoint web part that needs to use a single-threaded COM component. I've discovered that in order to make this work well, I need to add the AspCompat="true" directive to the page where the web part will live. The problem is I can't seem to set up such a page.

I created a new blank web part page via the regular browser interface, then added AspCompat to it using SharePoint Designer. But that causes it to become un-ghosted and the SafeMode parser says that directive isn't allowed. I then modified the blank web part page template to include the directive and created a new page, but got the same error.

I basically need to set up a page within my SharePoint site that is stored in the file system, has that directive, and can contain my web part. How would I go about creating such a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft SharePoint developer support, it is simply not possible to use AspCompat within a SharePoint site. The SPPageParserFilter class, which is the one that disallows certain page directives, is apparently involved in processing all pages, even those that are on the file system. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/malag/archive/2009/05/20/parser-error-the-async-attribute-on-the-page-directive-is-not-allowed-in-this-page.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627756/adding-web-page-to-blank-sharepoint-site-definition) with some instructions that includes how to supply new site content page templates that you can use to host web parts.  I think it's likely to work for you.

In your case, your aspx page template would have that AspCompat directive built-in.

Comment: Your answer to that other question seems promising. I figured I could just modify the existing feature manifest of my web part to include an ASPX page that contains AspCompat. When I went into the file containing the elements for my feature I could add another <module> element, but after I added a <file> element underneath it Visual Studio suddenly couldn't parse the package solution when in WSP View. The error it gave was 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2'. Do I need to create a new feature within my web part just for the ASPX page?

Comment: OK, the error was caused by not including the Path attribute in the <file> element.

Comment: I ended up creating a new solution package containing a module being deployed as a feature, similar to what you suggested in your other answer. The solution installs correctly and seems to put things in the right place. I see my ASPX page with AspCompat in the Pages library, however, when I browse to it I still get a message saying the AspCompat directive isn't allowed. I set the content type for the file to GhostableInLibrary. I know it's looking at the disk file because if I rename it I can no longer browse to it. Why would it still have a problem with that directive?